# ansible loop with include_variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook, there are multiple `yaml` files under `include_vars` section of the task as you see i am defining them individually one by one. I'm wondering if i can pass them through the loop.

I went through the google and [ansible doc link here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/include_vars_module.html) but i don't find `loop` example however, i see `with_first_found` but i don't want that.

### My playbook below

```
    ---
    - name: Creating aws host
      hosts: localhost
      connection: local
      become: yes
    
      tasks:
        - include_vars: awsvariable.yml
          no_log: true
        - include_vars: vaults/mysecrets.yml
          no_log: true
        - include_vars: vaults/mydev.yml
          no_log: true
        - include_vars: requirements.yml
```

### Below is what i am considering

Is this doable as below?

```
      tasks:
        - include_vars: "{{ item }}"
          loop:
            - awsvariable.yml
            - vaults/mysecrets.yml
            - vaults/mydev.yml
            - requirements.yml

OR

      tasks:
        - include_vars: ['awsvariable.yml', 'vaults/mysecrets.yml', 'vaults/mydev.yml', 'requirements.yml']
          no_log: true
```

Please suggest, if we can better align them some other way around.

ansible version: 2.9
BR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you are already close to your answer and yes `loop` should work, try to run your play in the dry run mode and set the `no_log: false` to see if your variables are getting expanded.

## Example:

```
$ ansible-playbook test_play.yml --check --ask-vault-pass
```

## your code

```
- include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - 'awsvariable.yml'
    - 'vaults/mysecrets.yml'
    - 'vaults/mydev.yml'
    - 'requirements.yml'
  no_log: true
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems the `include_vars` module can't work with loops. You could use the `include_task` module to loop over a file that has a single task to `include_vars`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    files_to_load: 
    - file1.yml
    - file2.yml
    - file3.yml

  tasks:

  - include_tasks: include_vars.yml
    loop: "{{ files_to_load }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: file_to_load
```

ant the `include_vars.yml` file:

```
- name: include vars {{ file_to_load }}
  include_vars: "{{ file_to_load }}"
```

**UPDATE**:

Regarding loop syntax that i tried and didnt work, the below attempts failed:

1st:

```
  - include_vars: "{{ item }}"
    loop: - "{{ files_to_load }}"
```

2nd:

```
  - include_vars: "{{ item }}"
    loop: 
    - "{{ files_to_load }}"
```

i am aware that this syntax works:

```
- name: Include variable files
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - "vars/file.yml"
    - "vars/anotherfile.yml"
```

but personally i dont find convenient the fact that you need to list the loop items on task level.

Comment: This is incorrect, `include_vars` works with both `loop` and `with_items`.

Comment: i updated my answer to list what exactly doesnt work with loops

Comment: Both your 1st and 2nd example will work if the `files_to_load` variable contains a list.

Comment: the `files_to_load` is a list as depicted in 1st PB.

Comment: Thank you guys for your inputs and answers , i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Use `dir` to include all the files in a folder.

```
- name: Include variable files
  include_vars:
    dir: vars
    extensions:
      - "yml"
```

Alternatively can use both `loop` or `with_items` to loop through the filenames and include them.

```
- name: Include variable files
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "vars/file.yml"
    - "vars/anotherfile.yml"
```

Or using the newer `loop`.

```
- name: Include variable files
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - "vars/file.yml"
    - "vars/anotherfile.yml"
```